# Rails keeping a file in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4, database-design

I have User and Attachment model

> attachment model

```
create_table :attachments do |t|
  t.attachment :file
  t.belongs_to :user
  t.timestamps null: false
end
```

I want to write some data line by line, for example user.name and user.surname, in attachments file and keep it in database. How can I create the file?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it. Use an active record callback to set the attributes before the attachment is created. First, create columns for the data you want on the attachments table.

```
create_table :attachments do |t|
  t.attachment :file
  t.string :name
  t.string :surname
  t.belongs_to :user
  t.timestamps null: false
end
```

Then define the callback.

**models/attachment.rb**

```
validates :user, presence: true

before_create :update_name_and_surname

def update_name_and_surname
  self.name = self.user.name
  self.surname = self.user.surname
end
```

Comment: I just ask how I create the file in attachments#create method and how I write them in the file

Comment: When I download the attachment, I want to saw user.name and surname in the file

Comment: I assumed you were using the paperclip gem because your migration has the 't.attachment' helper, which is specific to paperclip. You'll probably want to install a file upload gem like paperclip or carrierwave to write and store the file. If you don't want a gem, check out this section of the docs http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.0.6/form_helpers.html#uploading-files

Comment: I m using paperclip  to upload something different. I want to create the file this time

Comment: `path = "your_file/path"
data = "data you want to write"
File.open(path, "a") do |f|
  f.write(data)
end`. Maybe something like this in your controller.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on the paperclip stuff. Try it and test it. If not, just make it a string.

Comment: I want to use @attachment.file.path for the path but there is no file right now

Comment: `has_attached_file :file
                    :path => ':rails_root/non-public/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension' `, it is my path for the file